# Sorting a custom post type in pre_get_posts

Tags: php, query, pre-get-posts

I have a custom posttype "Talks" which have a custom field name start_date. The posts start_dates are the the past and in the future.

I need the future posts to come first with the start_date closest to today to be first and followed by second closest. Then after the future posts I need all the past posts with the newest post just after the future posts. Like this:

1. Talk held tomorrow
2. Talk held the day after tomorrow
3. Talk held yesterday
4. Talk held the day before yesterday

```php
            $today = date('Ymd');
            
            $meta_query = array(
                'key' => 'start_time',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'DATE'
            );
            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
            $query->set('orderby', array(
                'meta_value' => 'DESC',
                'date' => 'DESC'
            ));
            $query->set('posts_per_page', '10');
```

Can it be done?

**UPDATE 2nd**

As I see it this should be a solutions but it still does not work. The 'start_time_in_future' orderby does seem to change the sorting.

```php
function custom_sort_by_start_time( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $meta_query = array(
                'relation'              => 'OR',
                'start_time_in_future'  => array(
                    'key'                   => 'start_time',
                    'value'                 => date( 'd-m-Y H:i' ),
                    'compare'               => '>=',
                    'type'                  => 'DATETIME'
                ),
                'start_time'            => array(
                    'key'                   => 'start_time',
                    'value'                 => date( 'd-m-Y H:i' ),
                    'compare'               => '<',
                    'type'                  => 'DATETIME'
                )
            );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $query->set( 'orderby', array(
            'start_time_in_future' => 'ASC',
            'start_time' => 'DESC'
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_sort_by_start_time' );
```

Comment: look up the official docs for `WP_Query`, they contain examples of named `meta_query` clauses and setting the order using those named clauses

Comment: Do you mean like this:
´ $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'custom_field_value' => array(
                    'key'     => 'start_time',
                    'value'   => $today, 
                    'compare' => '>=', 
                    'type'    => 'DATE',
                ),
                'custom_field_value_02' => array(
                    'key'     => 'start_time',
                    'value'   => $today, 
                    'compare' => '<', 
                    'type'    => 'DATE', 
            ));

Comment: Honestly I would just use two separate queries for this and merge them before output.

Comment: @Shoelaced can you show my with an example of that?

Comment: You could do it by writing two `WP_Query`s and merging the posts: `array_merge( $firstquery->posts, $secondquery->posts )`, but if you need more advanced usage you could try [this](https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries). Or if you just want to display the list you could just output the two queries individually as normal and style them the same.

Comment: @Shoelaced Looks great. Can also work with the hook "pre_get_posts"? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Comment: I'm not sure. If you have to use a single query you could also try it without the date comparison and write your own function to sort the `$query->posts` array by date afterward, but I'm not sure how all this would work with pagination. I've managed it before -- if I remember where I'll look up what I did and post an answer!

Comment: you can't use 2 separate queries if you want to do pagination. Refer to the official docs for the example that shows meta query clauses and ordering by them. Each bullet point you listed would be a named clause

Comment: @TomJNowell can you show an example on this kind of query?

Comment: @JesperKahrNielsen the official docs already have an example, search the page for `WP_Query` on the official documentation for "‘orderby’ with multiple ‘meta_key’s". Any example I wrote myself would be deliberately misconfigured so that you couldn't just copy paste it, anybody reading would be forced to read and understand it.

Comment: the official WP dev docs for `WP_Query`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters, note that your edit includes multiple clauses, but they are _unnamed_ and don't match the examples. Think of it this way, what if WordPress came back to you and asked "what/where exactly is start_time_in_future?" You can't pull things out of thin air

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you. I have updated my question based on the documentation according to this paragraph: ‘orderby’ with multiple ‘meta_key’s

But the query does work as I expect. The 'orderby' with the two different values are not doing two different sorting.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're setting `meta_key`

Comment: @TomJNowell My mistake, sorry. But the removal of it did not make a change in the query. It seems like the query only use the first clause of the 'Orderby'?

Comment: did you declare the `type` of the meta in your meta query? Are you sure that your content provides enough variety to satisfy this while making sure that the number of events isn't so high that you have to go through multiple pages to reach posts that match `start_time` but don't match `start_time_in_future`? At this point, double check that everything does indeed do what you want it to do, that each individual clause brings back the right data, 
 etc, otherwise there's nothing more I can do to help without writing an answer, and I don't have the time and resources for the testing to do that

Comment: @TomJNowell again thank you for taking your time to pointing me in the right direction. I have added ´type´ and changed the date('d-m-Y H:i') so that is matches the stored data in the custom field. So maybe the trouble is the format of the custom field. I am also trying to isolate the problem to the clause about the future posts which seems to be the problem. I think that might be the problem – the format on the different dates. How do I force the format to be the same and use the correct one?

Comment: if your meta has a timestamp format, and you've specified that its meta type is `DATE` in your clauses then the database side should be taken care of

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter on [posts_clauses](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/) to;

- left join additional columns for each meta filter
- add order by clause base on those column values.

Something like below should work, assuming your meta key is `start_date` and the value has the actual date format `Y-m-d` and your post type is `talks`

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', function ($clauses, \WP_Query $q) {
    
    // exit if post type not talk, or in admin, or not main query, or not archive
    if ( $q->get('post_type') != 'talks' || is_admin() || !$q->is_main_query() || !is_archive() ) 
        return $clauses;


    // left join the meta key for future date (fd) and past date (pd)
    $clauses['join'] = "
    
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta fd ON (wp_posts.ID = fd.post_id)
                    AND fd.meta_key = 'start_date'
                    AND CAST(fd.meta_value AS DATE) >= CAST('".date('Y-m-d')."' AS DATE) 
                    
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pd ON (wp_posts.ID = pd.post_id)
                    AND pd.meta_key = 'start_date'
                    AND CAST(pd.meta_value AS DATE) < CAST('".date('Y-m-d')."' AS DATE)";
                    
     //order them first if fd value is null, followed by fd ascending order, then pd descending order
    $clauses['orderby'] = 'CASE WHEN fd.meta_value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CAST(fd.meta_value AS DATE) ASC, CAST(pd.meta_value AS DATE) DESC';
    
 
    return $clauses;
}, 1, 2 );
```

Comment: note that this was the method people used before named meta clauses became a thing, and still works. I would change this to use a named function rather than an anonymous function though as it makes stack traces easier to read

Comment: @TomJNowell, would love to see your sample with using meta_query that also includes post with empty start_date meta value